# Template's in C#

Tags: c#, templates

I am dealing with a lot of repeating code it is in the following form

```
        usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.FirstSubTag = Top3SubAngerFirst[0].Sub_Tag;
        usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.FirstSubTagScore = Top3SubAngerFirst[0].AngerEmotion;
        usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.SecondSubTag = Top3SubAngerFirst[1].Sub_Tag;
        usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.SecondSubTagScore = Top3SubAngerFirst[1].AngerEmotion;
        usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.ThirdSubTag = Top3SubAngerFirst[2].Sub_Tag;
        usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.ThirdSubTagScore = Top3SubAngerFirst[2].AngerEmotion;
```

I have to run these assignments for `usertags.Anger.` and `usertags.Happy.` How would I make it such that I do not have to write out this everytime.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't understand the question... You want to shorten your code and make it easier readable or you want to change the functionality in some way? If you want to just not type that every time, why don't you put that piece of code in a void with a reference to your "usertag" variable. You could use a for loop as well to make it more clear.

Comment: In my opinion the naming of the `First*`, `Second*`etc. members suggests that they would be better kept in an array. Then the solution would be obvious. If you can change that class, do that; if not, you can perhaps write a wrapper or accessor which keeps an array of references which point to the respective original members.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can try (you should change object to needed type):

```
   enum TagIndexEnum { First, Second, Third };
    public static void SetSubTag(TagIndexEnum tagIndex, object[] array, object subTags)
{
    switch (tagIndex)
    {
        case TagIndexEnum.First:
            subTags.FirstSubTag = array[0].Sub_Tag;
            subTags.FirstSubTagScore = array[0].AngerEmotion;
            break;
        case TagIndexEnum.Second:
            subTags.SecondSubTag = array[1].Sub_Tag;
            subTags.SecondSubTagScore = array[1].AngerEmotion;
            break;
        case TagIndexEnum.Third:
            subTags.ThirdSubTag = array[2].Sub_Tag;
            subTags.ThirdSubTagScore = array[2].AngerEmotion;
            break;

        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
    // Using    
    var subTags = usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags;
    // usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.FirstSubTag = Top3SubAngerFirst[0].Sub_Tag;
    // usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.FirstSubTagScore = Top3SubAngerFirst[0].AngerEmotion;
    SetSubTag(TagIndexEnum.First, Top3SubAngerFirst, subTags);

    // usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.SecondSubTag = Top3SubAngerFirst[1].Sub_Tag;
    // usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.SecondSubTagScore = Top3SubAngerFirst[1].AngerEmotion;
    SetSubTag(TagIndexEnum.Second, Top3SubAngerFirst, subTags);

    // usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.ThirdSubTag = Top3SubAngerFirst[2].Sub_Tag;
    // usertags.Anger.FirstMainTag.SubTags.ThirdSubTagScore = Top3SubAngerFirst[2].AngerEmotion;
    SetSubTag(TagIndexEnum.Third, Top3SubAngerFirst, subTags);
```